# Database query with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have got two tables **articles** and **tags** in the database. My goal was to retrieve all fields from **articles** table and one *category* field from **tags** table with Eloquent. I couldn't do this so instead I came up with the following method in my controller.

```
public function showCategory($category){
    $data = DB::select('select articles.*,
                                tags.category
                                from articles
                                join tags on articles.id = tags.article_id 
                                where lang = ? AND tags.category = ?', ['ru', $category]);

    return $data;
}
```

In my Article and Tag models a have those relationships, respectively:

*Article.php*

```
  public function tags(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Tag');
}
```

*Tag.php*

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

This implementation works for me, but I am still curious how can I achieve the same result with Eloquent and eager load tag's category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation `hasMany` required a correspondent field in the target table.

I guess in your case you want `manyToMany` relationship, you are currently using `oneToMany`.

Be careful about the grammar, an `Article belongsToMany Tags`, not `an Article hasMany Tags`.

After re-coding your relationships with `belongsToMany` method you can simply bind your articles and tags within a pivot table that contains both the `article_id` and `tag_id`.

As an example I would recommend having a look at a package in [GitHub](https://github.com/OzanKurt/KurtModules-Blog).
You should also have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for raw information about Many to Many relationships in Laravel.

When it comes to the query you send via Laravel's `Query\Builder`;

You can start trying it with an `Eloquent\Builder`

```
Article::join('tags', 'articles.id', '=', 'tags.article_id')
    ->where('articles.lang', '=', 'ru')
    ->where('tags.category', '=', $category)
    ->get([
        'articles.*', 
        'tags.category'
    ]);
```

If the select at the end confuses you, you can also use the select method on the `Query\Builder` to specify the columns you want.

```
Article::select([
        'articles.*', 
        'tags.category'
    ]) 
    // You could also give each element of this array 
    // as a parameter to the `select` method
    // It would look like this:
    //      select('articles.*', 'tags.category')
    ->join('tags', 'articles.id', '=', 'tags.article_id')
    ->where('articles.lang', '=', 'ru')
    ->where('tags.category', '=', $category)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out wrong relationships in Article model. I didn't notice something was not right there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I love it when people try to learn Laravel. :) Keep up buddy!